# How to improve Query optimization

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I created queuetable and it consist nearly 700 000 records. I created index for DateReceived. I written the below mongo query. it showing 1300 milliseconds of time in explain(). but I want to optimize if upto 300 miliseconds. here DateReceived is as String type

```
 db.queuetable.find(
  { Status: 0,
    CommunityId: { '$in': [ 2001, 2002, 2003, 82, 59, 123, 270, 170, 165, 3 ] },
    DateReceived: { '$gte': '2017-08-03 12:55:42' } 
  }).explain()
```

I added one mode field DateRec typeof Date, even it is taking 1560 min. find query below plz help any one. i Want to optimise it to 300

```
db.queuetable.find({ Status : 0, CommunityId: { '$in': [ 2001, 2002, 2003, 82, 59, 123, 270, 170, 165, 3 ] }, DateRec: { '$gte': ISODate("2017-08-03T08:59:56.467Z")} } ).explain()
```

Comment: You might have created an index on that field, but if it's not actually the one that makes the "smallest selection" then it's not that much use in affecting performance. Seems to me that the smallest "finite" identifiers would be on both `Status` and `CommunityId`, so you really should have a compound index on all those three fields in order to get the best result from the index. Also your dates are in fact "strings", and that means they take a lot more memory to store and load than they would as a BSON date. This will affect performance considerably. So fix your dates as well.

Comment: i added another fields DateRec as Date type and created index even it is same

Comment: db.queuetable.find({ Status : 0, CommunityId: { '$in': [ 2001, 2002, 2003, 82, 59, 123, 270, 170, 165, 3 ] }, DateRec: { '$gte': ISODate("2017-08-03T08:59:56.467Z")} } ).explain() Query

Comment: fields _id object
DateSent string
DateReceived string
status object
NotificationType string
Message string
MatriId string
_v object
CommunityId number
Status number
DateRec object

Comment: There is a [link to Edit Your Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45500916/edit) with additional details. Please use it.